# Why $xx^TM$ requires $O(dk)$ operations?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis

Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times k}$.

Why $xx^TM$ requires $O(dk)$ operations?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  What have you tried?  How many operations did you expect it to require?  Of course, since $M$ has a $dk$ elements, $dk$ is a lower bound.

Comment: @Pål GD : On column 2 on page second in line 27 of the following paper, it claims this question? http://ttic.uchicago.edu/~klivescu/papers/arora_etal_allerton2012.pdf

Comment: Try writing the formula for an entry of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $xx^T$ has the $(i,j)$th entry $x_i x_j$. Hence
$$
(xx^TM)_{ij} = \sum_k (xx^T)_{ik} M_{kj} = \sum_k x_i x_k M_{kj} = x_i \sum_k x_k M_{kj}.
$$
We can compute $\sum_k x_k M_{kj}$ for each $j$ in linear time. Given that, we can compute the product matrix in linear time using the above formula.